GDAL Warp extremely slow on Python API
I am trying to export one VRT to TIFF using GDAL Warp. My VRT has some scale, offset, reprojections, etc, but nothing too crazy.
I have observed that trying to perform the warp from the Python API is way slower than just running it on the command line.
This:
from osgeo import gdal
gdal.Warp(output_path, # Some path for the .tiff
          mosaic_path,  # the VRT
         )

is over 10 times slower than this:
import subprocess
command_to_execute = ["gdalwarp", mosaic_path, output_path]
run = subprocess.run(command_to_execute, capture_output=True)

Is this expected behavior or is there any reason for this?
I'm currently on the latest GDAL version (3.9.1) and Python 3.11.9
In order to reproduce this behavior, this what one of my simple VRT for one single Sentinel-2 band file look like:
<VRTDataset rasterXSize="10980" rasterYSize="10980">
  <SRS dataAxisToSRSAxisMapping="1,2">PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 18N",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-75],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","32618"]]</SRS>
  <GeoTransform>  6.0000000000000000e+05,  1.0000000000000000e+01,  0.0000000000000000e+00,  4.5000000000000000e+06,  0.0000000000000000e+00, -1.0000000000000000e+01</GeoTransform>
  <VRTRasterBand dataType="UInt16" band="1">
    <Description>B08</Description>
    <NoDataValue>0</NoDataValue>
    <Offset>-0.1</Offset>
    <Scale>0.0001</Scale>
    <SimpleSource>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">downloads/L2A_T18TXK_2023-07-11_CC0.021/B08.jp2</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
      <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="10980" ySize="10980" />
      <DstRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="10980" ySize="10980" />
    </SimpleSource>
  </VRTRasterBand>
</VRTDataset>

Building the TIFF with the first method takes around 6.6 secs and the second method takes 4.8 secs.
I'm using several VRTs like this one to build a bigger mosaic that includes more bands, reprojects all to the same UTM, clips the result to an AOI and then, from this VRT of VRTs, generates the raster.
As the VRT gets more and more complicated, this difference starts increasing up until around 40 secs vs 1 hour. The first method took around 1h40min to compose a 5.5 GB mosaic of 9 tiles with 4 bands each. At first I thought that the slowness was related to reading the files directly from a private S3 with /vsis3/ but downloading the bands locally gives roughly the same performance.
I have also noted that all of my machine's cores are working all the time even when using the slow method, which confuses me even more.
gdalinfo of the final VRT outputs:
Driver: VRT/Virtual Raster
Files: ./testbench/output/mosaic_clipped.vrt
       ./testbench/output/mosaic.vrt
Size is 25956, 13051
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 18N",
    BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4326]],
    CONVERSION["UTM zone 18N",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-75,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["easting",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["northing",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    ID["EPSG",32618]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (524180.603418433107436,4596544.668357357382774)
Pixel Size = (10.000249346459958,-10.000249346459940)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  524180.603, 4596544.668) ( 74d42'36.69"W, 41d31'12.63"N)
Lower Left  (  524180.603, 4466031.414) ( 74d42'55.03"W, 40d20'40.14"N)
Upper Right (  783747.075, 4596544.668) ( 71d36' 7.61"W, 41d28'13.16"N)
Lower Right (  783747.075, 4466031.414) ( 71d39'42.07"W, 40d17'47.90"N)
Center      (  653963.839, 4531288.041) ( 73d10'17.81"W, 40d55' 5.59"N)
Band 1 Block=512x128 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
  NoData Value=0
  Offset: -0.1,   Scale:0.0001


Can you publicly share a minimal file that reproduces this behaviour?

Do you mean a VRT that reproduces the error or the Python code where I'm running these samples?

I updated the question to add more info

Have you tried with the Python function https://gdal.org/api/python/utilities.html#osgeo.gdal.Warp instead of using subprocess?

@user30184 that's the whole point of the question, why gdal.Warp is 10x slower than gdal_warp.

I can't reproduce. Using your VRT and some S2A in UTM18N downloaded from dataspace.copernicus.eu I get both gdal.Warp and gdalwarp running in ~2.8 seconds (gdal 3.9.0).

for one tile the performance is around the same in both cases for me as well. but when the VRT gets more complex, such as adding reprojections or resampling of different tiles, that's when the difference become huge
